# Hana Column Store dialect to Oracle 12c SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c, hana

While trying to benchmark Oracle's [Database Inmemory](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/features/database-in-memory-option/), we were looking for publicly available benchmarking data set and tools. The [CH-benCHmark](http://www-db.in.tum.de/research/projects/CHbenCHmark/) suited our requirement exactly, but it has HANA Column Store Dialect as part of the source files.

So, our requirement is to convert these [HANA Column Store dialect](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/inmemory/SAP+HANA+commonly+used+SQL) SQLs to Oracle 12c SQLs. Google search returned the conversion from Oracle to Hana dialect not the reverse.

Has anyone came across this requirement? Is there a simple/direct way to do the conversion?

Any pointers will be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have done this exercise! there's no direct way from HANA Dialect to Oracle Dialect, But you can make use of ORACLE_LOADER and it's semantics to effectively create Oracle Dialect! Only problem you may face would be the flow, where HANA's flow is totally different from Oracle's schema creation flow.

For example:
you can easily use LOAD FROM  FILE... syntax in HANA, But you need an externally organized table in case of Oracle.